# Work done by centrifugal force brings energy conservation violation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

The rotating body with ${m}_1$ mass rotates with angular speed ${\omega}_a$, with a $r$ distance from the center of rotation. The rotating body is kept in orbit by means of a rope which is considered massless. The rope goes through a funnel whose friction with the rope is negligible. And on the other end of the rope another body with mass $m_2$ is hanging. The system is in equilibrium, that is to say, the weight of the hanging body $P=m_2g$ is equal to the centrifugal force of the rotating body. $F_c = m_1{{\omega}_a}^2r$

$$m_2g=m_1{{\omega}_a}^2r$$

And this is the kinetic energy of the rotating body in this situation $$ E_{ka} = \frac{1}{2}m_1{\omega_a}^2r^2 $$

[image]

Now the situation a has changed. **Very slowly** we increased the kinetic energy of the rotating body, therefore increased its centrifugal force, and lifted the hanging body until a new equlibrium was reached.

[image]

Now the rotating body rotates with a new angular speed ${\omega_b}$, and its new radius of rotation is $r+h$. And the hanging body was lifted an $h$ height. Here the system is also in equilibrium, that is to say that the centrifugal force of the rotating body is equal to the weight of the hanging body. The weight of the hanging body in this new situation is the same as its weight in the previous situation, logically it hasn't change. Therefore the centrifugal force of the rotating body in this situation $F_c = m_1{\omega_b}^2(r+h)$ must be the same as in the previous one. That is  $$m_1{{\omega}_a}^2r =  m_1{\omega_b}^2(r+h)$$

From this we isolate ${\omega_b}^2$

$${\omega_b}^2 = {\omega_a}^2\frac{r}{r+h}$$

And this is the kinetic energy of the rotating body in the new situation $$E_{kb} = \frac{1}{2}m_1{\omega_b}^2(r+h)^2$$

Here we replace ${\omega_b}^2$ for ${\omega_a}^2\frac{r}{r+h}$ and we get

$$E_{kb} = {\frac{1}{2}}m_1{\omega_a}^2r(r+h)$$

Now lets calculate the difference of the kinetic energy between the first and the situation $$ {\Delta}E_k = E_{kb}-E_{ka} = \frac{1}{2}m_1{\omega_a}^2r((r+h)-r)$$

That is
$$ {\Delta}E_k = \frac{1}{2}m_1{\omega_a}^2rh$$

Earlier we had found that $m_2g=m_1{{\omega}_a}^2r$, therefore the difference of the kinetic energy between the first and the second situations is

$${\Delta}E_k = \frac{1}{2}m_2 gh$$

This is the **amount of energy given to the system** to increase the speed of the rotating body and to lift the hanging body an $h$ height.

But what is the amount of work necessary to lift any object of mass $m_2$ to a height $h$ using a crane or a bare hand? That is

$$W=m_2gh$$

As you can see
$$\frac{{\Delta}E_k}{W} = \frac{1}{2}$$

The calculations show that lifting an object by using centrifugal force you pay with 50% less energy. If you think that there must be a mistake, please point it out.


Again, using centrifugal force I can show you another situation where energy is "destroyed". But I am not writing it down to not to make my post even longer.

---

Errata

"centrifugal force" = "centripetal force"
As in engineering applications terms like "centrifugal force" or "centrifuge" are used, I decided to use to do the same. However if this was the reason for closing my post, I apologize, this is the correction.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146735/discussion-on-question-by-eduard-oganesian-work-done-by-centrifugal-force-brings); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many things to complain about your post.

1. Your algebraic manipulations may be correct, but you are just randomly throwing things together and not systematically doing valid comparisons.
2. Centrifugal effect *is not a force and cannot be doing anything real.*
   \begin{align}\tag1
   \text{KE}_i=\frac12m_1\omega_i^2r^2\qquad&\implies\qquad\omega_i^2r^2=\frac2{m_1}\text{KE}_i\\
   \therefore\qquad m_2g&=m_1\omega_i^2r=\frac2r\text{KE}_i\tag2
   \end{align}
   It is easy to see that the same argument on the final situation just gives us
   $$\tag3\frac2{r+h}\text{KE}_f=m_2g=\frac2r\text{KE}_i$$
   $$\tag4\therefore\qquad\Delta\text{KE}=\frac12m_2g[(r+h)-r]=\frac12m_2gh$$
   Which is what you obtained after so much effort.

---

But what is the actual energy difference? To do that, we need to look at
\begin{align}\tag5
\text{CoE}:\qquad\sum E_i+W&=\sum E_f\\
\text{KE}_i+\text{GPE}_i+W&=\text{KE}_f+\text{GPE}_f\tag6\\
W&=\Delta\text{KE}+\Delta\text{GPE}\tag7\\
&=\frac32m_2gh\tag8
\end{align}
That is, you not only had to input energy to raise the mass at the centre, but also input energy to speed up the rotating mass. *You are NOT paying "50% less energy".*

Your initial analysis is just too sloppy to have considered the situation properly enough.

---

Note that your $\omega_b=\omega_a\sqrt{\frac r{r+h}}$ shows that the angular velocity decayed a little upon the raise, but this corresponds to $v_b=(r+h)\omega_b=\sqrt{\frac{r+h}r}v_a$ i.e. the raised situation has the rotating mass moving slightly faster, despite the angular velocity decreasing.

*There is nothing particularly interesting in the situations you are looking at here.*

Comment: +1 I think the OP is using the word _centrifugal_ in place of _centripetal_. Although a constant centripetal force does no work, if $\omega$
 increases, the path of the spinning object changes from circular to something else (elliptical maybe) so that F can have components along $r$, meaning  work done need not be zero.

Comment: Great answer, I thought that too. "input energy to raise the mass at the centre, but also input energy to speed up the rotating mass" But now imagine the reverse situation. The system is in balance, we remove the hanging body and replace it with another one with greater mass. The new hanging body will lower, the radius of the rotation will decrease the centrifugal force will increase and a new balance will be reached. However the kinetic energy of the rotating body will not decrease. Can you explain where where the gravitational potential energy of the hanging body went?